# MySQL combine data from multiple tables into one table

Tags: mysql

I have 27 tables of monthly web analytics with the following format:

```
+---------------+-------+
| url           | views |
+---------------+-------+
| /foo/bar.php  | 200   |
| /bar/foo.html | 500   |
+---------------+-------+
```

I need to combine them into a single table with a unique 'url' field like:

```
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| url           | views_2009_01 | views_2009_02 |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
| /foo/bar.php  | 200           | 700           |
| /bar/foo.html | 500           |               |
| /snafu.html   |               | 500           |
+---------------+---------------+---------------+
```

To accomplish this I created a temporary table:

```
+---------------+-------+------------+
| url           | views | date       |
+---------------+-------+------------+
| /foo/bar.php  | 200   | 2009-01-01 |
| /bar/foo.html | 500   | 2009-01-01 |
| /foo/bar.php  | 700   | 2009-02-01 |
| /snafu.html   | 500   | 2009-02-01 |
+---------------+-------+------------+
```

In which the 'url' field isn't unique and added a date field.

I imported each table of analytics and appended a date to each record.

I then imported just the urls into my final table like so:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO target (url)
SELECT S.url
FROM temp S;
```

I then did an UPDATE for each of the original monthly tables like so:

```
UPDATE temp S, target T
SET T.views_200910 = S.views
WHERE S.url = T.url && S.date = '2009-10-01';
```

My question is, is there a more elegant way of achieving the same outcome?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A column for every year/month? What happens if this code/db is still in operations 10+ years down the road? 120 new columns? You should normalize this design...

Comment: We are only analysing data in 3 year blocks.

Comment: you should use the design of your temporary table for your main table. Unless you are planning to add new columns to your table every month....